# Why are varargs and arrays sometimes incompatible?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

there is a method like this:

```
tableHeader(final String first, final String second, final String third, final String... headers) {
```

I think I should be able to call the method like this:

```
tableHeader("first", "second", "third", new String []{"hello", "world"}) {
```

But it does not compile. So basically I can not pass a String array where it expects vararg parameter.

Comment: What's the exact wording of the compilation error?

Comment: It should compile . What is the compiler complaining ?

Comment: That's why we usually post the error if it exists. Please avoid posting questions with "Errors" without mentioning the actual error.

Comment: Gentlemen, it was my fault. I does compile. What I posted was a simplified version of a much more complex method call, and I miscalculated the numbers of parameters passed (in the original)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Test
{
void go()
{
    foo("first", "second", "third", new String []{"hello", "world"});

}
 void foo(String first, final String second, final String third, final String... headers) {}

}
```

It seems it compiles fine O.o

If you have Compilation error please post it in question itself !!